# How to execute cd commands with apple script

Tags: macos, command, applescript, applescript-objc

I have written a program to execute the commands in cocoapp using apple script. There are 2 issues am facing
1) the applescript is exceuting always from the projet directory not from the root
2)cd command is working , but when i do pwd it shows the previous directory name not the new one.

```
+(BOOL)callAppleScriptForScriptFile:(NSString *)command{
    BOOL isError = YES;
NSAppleEventDescriptor* returnDescriptor = NULL;
NSDictionary* errorDict = nil;

NSString *appleScriptCommand = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"do shell script \" %@  &> /Users/username/Desktop/.output.txt\"  user name \"username\" password \"password\" with administrator privileges",command];
    //NSLog(@"Script command %@",appleScriptCommand);
NSAppleScript* scriptObject = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:appleScriptCommand];


returnDescriptor = [scriptObject executeAndReturnError: &errorDict];
if (errorDict != NULL){
    NSLog(@"%@",errorDict);
    isError = NO;
}
DescType descriptorType = [returnDescriptor descriptorType];
NSLog(@"descriptorType == %@", NSFileTypeForHFSTypeCode(descriptorType));
NSData *data = [returnDescriptor data];
double currentPosition = 0;
[data getBytes:&currentPosition length:[data length]];
NSLog(@"currentPosition == %f", currentPosition);
[self readFromFileAndSend];
return isError;
```

}

Expecting output like this
cd Desktop
o/p: sucess(no need to print)
pwd
o/p: Desktop

Comment: Everything in the **do shell script** statement runs in the same environment, that is, the one it inherited when called from the parent, so you need to include all the commands in the same statement - what command string are you using?

Comment: i am not using pipelined commands. i am trying to replicate an app which works like terminal.
One by one i will pass the command

Answer (score 2):

Each `do shell script` statement uses a new shell process, so you can't do something like change the working directory in one statement and then expect it to be the same in another. For example, if you use the separate statements

```
do shell script "cd ~/Desktop"
do shell script "pwd"
```

the second statement will show the root directory, because it is starting over - it doesn’t have anything to do with the first statement.  You need to include all the commands in the same statement

```
do shell script "cd ~/Desktop; pwd"
```

From a Cocoa application, you can also use NSTask, which would avoid all the Apple Event stuff.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any way I can achieve this requirement.

Comment: @Angel did you find a solution?

Comment: No. I didn't pursue further.